# Pearson Hash implementation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, hash, pearson

I have to write this Pearson Hash for school, but I never heard of it so it's difficult to imagine how it works. That is makes things more difficult that I learned haskell a long time ago and I almost forgot it.

Here is the thing:
They gave me that the syntac of this function will be this:

```
pearsonHash :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
```

and the algorithm of Pearson Hash is:

```
h := 0
for each c in C loop
    index := h xor c
    h := T[index]
end loop
return h
```

They said, that: Let *C* be the input sequence of bytes, and *h* the value to be calculated. And the first parameter of pearson hash should a a predefined *T* list which contains a permutation of `[0..255]`.

There are the test cases:

```
pearsonHash ([0..127] ++ [255,254..128]) [1..10]   ==  11
pearsonHash [255,254..0] [ ord c | c <- "Hello" ]  ==  189
```

I think they should be `True`.

This is just a part of the work (meaning this is only one function from a lot), so I don't want you to solve this instead of me, I just need help how to solve this function because I got stuck with this one.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: It is unclear what problem you have. Stack Overflow is not a tutoring site. Be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
h := 0
for each c in C loop
    index := h xor c
    h := T[index]
end loop
return h
```

OK, so this looks pretty imperative. When you see a loop like this, what you probably want to do is turn the "loop body" into a function, and then the loop itself will be either `foldr` or `foldl`. So your code ends up looking something like

```
hashStep :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int
hashStep ts h c = ...???...

pearsonHash :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
pearsonHash ts cs = foldr (hash_step ts) 0 cs
```

Now, can you figure out what `hashStep` should do?

Comment: After a quick brainstorm I would say the hashStep function will lokk like this:

hashStep :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
hashStep ts h = ts!!(h xor c) | c <- ts

But I have to think it through correctly and test it.
I am sure I can figure it out on my own.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid didn't even look at the type signature.. thought you are suggesting a lambda and proposed a more obvious way :)

Comment: I got the answer!

hashStep :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Int
hashStep ts h c = ts!!(xor h c)
Thanks a lot for the help again!